# How to get a value from a self populated dropdown using knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a select menu that is populated using the `foreach` data bind:

```
self.priorityOptions = ko.observableArray(["Low", "Normal", "High"]);

<select data-bind="options: priorityOptions"></select>
```

This works perfectly fine, but I'm using this dropdown to create objects in another array, but I'm trying to use that dropdown to specify one of the object's parameters:

```
self.createTicket = function() {
    self.tickets.push({priority: *********});
}
```

If I put an actual string where the asterisks are, the object is created correctly, but that means I need to manually type each one. Is there a binding I can use on the `select` element in order to pull which choice is currently selected and insert that into the array push?

I've seen `selectedOptions` but I could not get that to successfully work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select is not "multiple", so I guess you have a button and you want to create your ticket with the selected priority at that moment. Bind your selected value to your view model, then use the value in your `createTicket` function.

```
self.priorityOptions = ko.observableArray(["Low", "Normal", "High"]);
self.selectedPriority = ko.observable();

<select data-bind="options: priorityOptions , value: selectedPriority"></select>

self.createTicket = function() {
    self.tickets.push({priority: self.selectedPriority()});
}
```